# Why does the Torah allow "tzorech ochel nefesh" on Yom Tov?

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, ochel-nefesh

Are there any explanations as to why the Torah allows ochel nefesh on Yom Tov (in contrast with Shabbat)?

It is indeed very practical, especially in chutz laaretz, on a two-day Yom Tov (or even on a single day adjacent to Shabbat), but there must be some deeper explanation.

Comment: I've identified a few sources, but haven't browse them through. Meshech Chochma here: https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Meshekh_Chokhmah/Shemot/12.16#m7e0n6 (s.v. יתכן דכיון דפירש), and the sources here: https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/537878?lang=bi (Likutei Halachot long, starting from this piece).

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/12-03-01/

Comment: It's worth considering what your shabbos would be like without a fridge or plata, without an eruv, and without electric lights.